# How to validate if a string is a valid date in js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have string field which is used to get different values. Some of the values received are dates. Now I need to check if value received is date or not? The date received can be in different formats again.

I tried `Date.parse()`, it works if format is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`, but I have some dates received in like (`26/05/2015 06:20:57 +00:00`).

How do I compare if string is valid date or not?

Comment: Try looking at moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/) its a pretty strong date library. You would be able to try to create a date with any value then check to see if it is valid

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but the linked dupe has mostly poor answers that simply rely on *Date.parse*, which is very unreliable for random formats.

Comment: It is fundamental to correctly parsing a date string that you can tell the parser what format it is in (or supply a format you **know** it will parse correctly). Otherwise, you can just try a sequence of different formats and stop when you get one that "works". Where the year is first, you can be reasonably certain of y-m-d sequence, but where the year is last, the prevalence of the illogical m/d/y sequence means you can't reliably tell if 04/05/2010 is 4 May or April 5.

Comment: @RobG Good point. I added some fresh info [**in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value/30870755#30870755) to the linked dupe.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the "luxon" package from the same moment.js team. https://moment.github.io/luxon This is a lifesaver. I have worked on many super complex projects where the validity of date, durations, and intervals are important and luxon seems to be the best in the market.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `Date.parse()` is not enough for you - but it may be enough - see the documentation at:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

then you may try:

- [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It is a library to parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript, that has a much richer API than the standard JavaScript date handling functions.

See also [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value/30870755#30870755) for more libraries and links to tutorials.

Comment: thanks. use of moment.js  helps. I  can parse string to match any format I want.

Comment: using moment.js just for validating a string does not look correct. Is there any pure JavaScript solution available ?

Comment: `Date.parse()` should not be used, since it will accept any string with a number in it as a valid date - check comments on [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445368/1876359](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7445368/1876359).

Comment: @ocramot Yes, you're right, see also [my other answer on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value/30870755#30870755) where I explain it in more detail.