# Invalid date string getting converted to date object

Tags: javascript, date

I have written a `function` to check whether a `string` is date string or not.
Here's my function.

```
function isDate(dateString) {var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
    return ((dateObject) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(dateObject)) ? true : false;
}
```

It gives following results.

```
isDate("12345");// return true
isDate("temp");//return false
isDate("temp - 123456");// return true
```

In the last case I don't know why it is not giving me `false`. Please help.

Comment: Why not use  `Date.parse()`  ?

Comment: All three cases should return false... even the first case. Are you sure this is the code that you used?

Comment: On which browser are you testing it?

Comment: that is because `new Date("temp - 123456")` is parsing the string

Comment: @ArunPJohny Obviously. But how is it parsing it to conclude that result?

Comment: @RGraham because `"12345"` is a string, not a number. If you pass a number, it gets interpreted as milliseconds since 1970 Jan 1. If you pass a string, it gets interpreted as a date string.

Comment: @light Right. It seems that whatever method is parsing is just looking for any year value first

Comment: @OP - Not an answer, but bottom line is your test for a date is invalid. You can't have a parser which understands all date/formats. You need to put some restrictions on the input string. Using Regex to match a given format first would be a good start. This is also a good reason to [read the comments on answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value#comment-49738547) before using copy/paste :)

Comment: that last one _is_  a date string, at least in the very forgiving V8 core

Comment: @All I have created the fillde for it http://jsfiddle.net/hitesh_kumar/8uaeesu2/ Please update the fiddle and make it working as expected.