# AngularJS : isDate() returns false if passed argument is not a Date object

Tags: angularjs

I just try to check a string whether a date or not. This is my code in angular JS.

```
var mydt= "2015/07/29"; 
document.write(angular.isDate(mydt));
```

This always return false.
But actually this is a date.

But when I try this code,

```
var cur_date = new Date(); 
document.write(cur_date);    
document.write(angular.isDate(cur_date));
```

The executed result is,

*Wed Jul 29 2015 15:15:13 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)
true*

I'm wondering why we cannot check simple date format like "yyyy/mm/dd" in simple way.

Answer (score 4):

`angular.isDate()` checks if the input is of type Date. 
Function source from **AngularJS**

```
function isDate(value) {
  return toString.call(value) === '[object Date]';
}
```

That's why angular.isDate returned true on a Date object, but false on a string.

```
var d = new Date('7/29/2015');
alert(angular.isDate(d)); // Alerts true on the date object
alert(d.toString()); // Alerts the string value of the date object
alert(angular.isDate(d.toString())); // Alerts false on the string value
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvx42pj8/)

You can use Date.parse():

[Check if a string is a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValidDate(dateString) {
  var regEx = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
  return dateString.match(regEx) != null;
}
```

check if string contains number four-two-two

Comment: Fails on 0000-00-00