# Check if string is date or not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

From server, I am getting valid date for some values in object, But I don't know for which field I will get number and for which field I will get date.

I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445328/2034794) question and its answers, It was giving correct result for string and dates, but now It is treating number as date. Any other solution to avoid treating number as date?

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse) question is to parse the date in different format. And my question is about distinguishing between date and number string. And performing operations on only date strings.**

**I am getting date in yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+Z.**

Comment: What do you mean by "is a date?"  Do you mean matches a particular format?  Which format?  Why not just use that answer with a switch on `typeof`?

Comment: If you get the value 2015, than it could be the number 2015 (integer) or the year 2015 and thus a date. You need some criteria to distinguish numbers from dates since they can be both under certain circumstances.

Comment: What is "GMT" format? GMT is a timezone, not a format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Date.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Comment: @cezar, Yes thats the problem, I can't distinguish between date and time, Sometime date is with time and for some keys it is without time.

Comment: @RahulTripathi, I already mentioned the reference, Please read question before flagging, It is not the parsing issue, is date or not issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got the solution**

Instead of checking if it is date or not, I need to check first if it is number or not. If it is not number then only it can be a date.

Here is What I did and it worked.

```js
var obj={
  key1:"2015-10-10T11:15:30+0530",
  key2:2015,
  key3:"Normal String"
}

function parseDate(dateStr){
  if(isNaN(dateStr)){ //Checked for numeric
    var dt=new Date(dateStr);
    if(isNaN(dt.getTime())){ //Checked for date
      return dateStr; //Return string if not date.
    }else{
      return dt; //Return date **Can do further operations here.
    }
  } else{
    return dateStr; //Return string as it is number
  }
}

console.log("key1 ",parseDate(obj.key1))
console.log("key2 ",parseDate(obj.key2))
console.log("key3 ",parseDate(obj.key3))
```