# Date parsing for "S.01.01.01" returns wrong value

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. In javaScript i have to check the particular string is valid date or not. So i use Date.Parse("S.01.01.01"). But it was return the following answer (978287400000) instead of "S.01.01.01".I need to maintain this as "S.01.01.01". In C# DateTime.TryParse method can be used and this returns the proper validation for DateTime. But in javascript i have wrong result. How to solve this?

Regards,
Pavithra K.

Comment: Pass the milliseconds into `new Date(here)`, if you want to use a resulting `Date` Object. I believe passing an invalid date might just alter the date, though, depending. Remember the Client can change JavaScript too, so you should probably take care of it on the Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string is a date value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value)

Comment: Aside from anything else, neither `Date` in Javascript nor `DateTime` in .NET maintains a format. When you parse a value, you just get the date/time as the result, with no indication of what format it was parsed in. It's really unclear what you'd *expect* to happen when you parse "S.01.01.01".

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Is this you want?

```js
var dd=Date.parse('S.01.01.01')
console.log(dd);
if (isNaN(dd)==false)
{
    var date=new Date(dd);
    console.log(date);
}
```

Comment: No,this is not i want. Date.Parse() method treats "S.01.01.01"  as date and return (Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). My need is Date.Parse() should return "s.01.01.01" as string.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking, But how can you think that date function(Date.parse()) return string?

Comment: Please imagine..if i pass the invalid argument like string("ad") to Date.Parse() means what it will be return(invalid date). But when i pass "S.01.01.01" to parse() method it will treat this string as date(like jan-1-2001). I need to solve this problem. It should not take this as date.