# How to convert date to the specified string format in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm reading a file's modification date with `fs.statSync()` and I'd like to compare it with a String that comes from my database:

This is my file's last modification date:

```
Fri Mar 24 2017 13:22:01 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

And I'd like to compare with this string:

```
2016-07-18 12:28:12
```

How can I do this with Node.JS? Can I somehow create a new date from the String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) parse both of those formats and compare the results.

```
var date1 = moment(string1, format1, true);
var date2 = moment(string2, format2, true);
if (date1.diff(date2) === 0) {
    // equal
} else {
    // not equal
}
```

See this answer for parsing dates in different formats:

- [Check if a string is a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value/30870755#30870755)

Make sure that you parse it with explicit format and you don't let it guess the format, or otherwise you will never be sure if it guessed correctly.