# Check if JavaScript string represents Date

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with checking if the string represents `Date`. Currently I have a situation where I need to check if `"Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Georgian Standard Time)"` this string represents `Date`. I wrote the following code:

```
var tryConvert = new Date(input);
var tryMonth = tryConvert.getMonth();
if (!(tryMonth !== tryMonth)) {//checking for NaN
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that input can be integer `96` and it successfully returns true. The desired behavior is that it should work only for `Date` instances, `ISO` strings `/\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\dT\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d/g` and `Date.toString()` strings like `"Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Georgian Standard Time)"`. How can I achieve this?

To make it more clear here is the full code:

```
function isDate(input) {
    if (!input) {
        return false;
    }

    if (input instanceof Date) {
        return true;
    }

    var rx = /\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\dT\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d/g;
    var time = rx.exec(input);

    if (time) {
        return true;
    }

    if (typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String) {
        var tryConvert = new Date(input);
        var tryMonth = tryConvert.getMonth();
        if (!(tryMonth !== tryMonth)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Use that regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string is a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value)

Comment: moment.js is a nice lib for dates handling that has a parse method for a specific pattern. Maybe it could help?

Comment: @SLaks, not sure what will be (new Date).toString() for user from US for example. How can I create a good regex for it?

Comment: https://date-fns.org/ as an alternative to momentjs.

Comment: Here is another thread with some solutions: [Detecting an “invalid date” Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript)

Comment: Would using an `isNaN(input)` check in combination with your `typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String` check accomplish what you need? `isNaN()` would be able to distinguish between the `96` string and an actual date string.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm, no I have tried it. `new Date("5555");` is a valid date :(

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Yes, but I mean if you return false if `!isNaN(input)` without even creating a date. `isNaN("5555") === false` but `isNaN("Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Georgian Standard Time)") === true`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm, hmm let me see that!

Comment: @MikaelLennholm, you are my hero today! Please add your comment as an answer!

Comment: Alright! I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, combining your check if `input` is a string with a check if it's a parseable number or not should do the trick.

Here I've added added this check where you check if `input` is a string:

```
if ((typeof input === 'string' || input instanceof String) && isNaN(input)) {
    var tryConvert = new Date(input);
    var tryMonth = tryConvert.getMonth();
    if (!(tryMonth !== tryMonth)) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Basically, this returns `false` if `input` is a string containing `96`, `5555` or any other parseable number but actual date strings such as `Tue May 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Georgian Standard Time)` are not parseable numbers so they will pass the `isNaN()` check and proceed to the conversion test.

You can probably remove the RegExp test as well since it only tests one particular date format.