# How to know string value is an instance of Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, typeof, object-type

I want to  check string value is Date or not ? I use the following code but dose not work:

```
const date = "2019-12-31T20:30:00+00:00";
if (date instanceof Date) {
    // date is Date....
}
```

or

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]') {
  // date is Date....
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string is a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value)

Comment: How about this one `new Date(dateValue)!="Invalid Date"`

Comment: @gorak `new Date("2020") != "Invalid Date"` but this is also not a valid date string.

Comment: @gorak, `new Date("2020") != "Invalid Date" ` I think This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'Date' and 'string' have no overlap

Comment: @swapnesh yes, got it.

Answer (score -1):

Your first condition is always true because of you are not converting `string` to `Date`. There is two way you can do this.

First, you can construct a Date object with given string and check whether Date is valid or not

```
const dateString = '2019-12-31T20:30:00+00:00';
const date = new Date(dateString);

if(date.toString() !== "Invalid Date") {
    // String is valid date.
} else {
    // String is not valid date.
}
```

The other way is, firstly you can check the given string is valid date and then consruct a Date object.

```
 const dateString = '2019-12-31T20:30:00+00:00';
 const parsed = Date.parse(dateString);

 if(!isNaN(parsed)) {
     // String is valid date.
     const date = new Date(parsed);
 } else {
     // String is not a valid date.
 }
```

Comment: If I change the value of dateString to `"1"` it always returns true while It's not a valid date;

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)