# check if the data in array is string or date and convert accordingly

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I want to check whether the data coming from loop in p-table is of string type or date type

I have a key named newValue
whose value can be either `newValue: "Percentage"` or `newValue: "2021-03-25T15:55:42.136Z"`

If its date I want to show the data as `"3/25/21, 9:25 PM"` else normal string `"Percentage"`

```
 <td style="width: 10%;">
        {{rowData?.histories.newValue ? getDateorStringValue(rowData?.histories.newValue) : 'N/A'}}
      </td>
    getDateorStringValue(...)
```

is the function I am using any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What does `getDateorStringValue(...)` looks like ?

Comment: Its empty for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a quick pipe to do the comparison.

**date-or-string.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";

export const isDate = (date: string) => {
  return !!Date.parse(date);
};

@Pipe({
  name: "dateOrString"
})
export class DateOrStringPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    super(locale);
  }

  transform(
    value: any,
    format?: string,
    timezone?: string,
    locale?: string
  ): any {
    return isDate(value)
      ? super.transform(value, format, timezone, locale)
      : value;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```html
<td style="width: 10%;">
  {{ rowData.histories.newValue | dateOrString:'M/dd/yy, h:mm a'}}
</td>
```

Note that the condition using `Date.parse()` might only work when compared against string. There are better ways to compare that you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445328/6513921).

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3wdvnh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) locale: string) {
    super(locale);
  }

what is the use of this?

Comment: It's the Angular standard `Date` pipe's [constructor parameter](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.7/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L156). Since we are extending the standard `Date` pipe, it must be passed in our child class's constructor.

Comment: !!Date.parse(date)
it returns true if value is 50, which is wrong
but return false if value is 25, which is correct
why?

@michael-d